# TeamCity treating PowerShell parameter as a string

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I got a Build Configuration Template in my Root project.

In the Parameters section, I have the following 3 configuration parameters:

```
deployment.username

deployment.password

deployment.destinationServer01
```

In the Parameters section, I also have `powershell.args01` configuration parameter with the value of

```
-username %deployment.username% -password %deployment.password% -computer %deployment.destinationServer01%
```

In the same template, I have a "PowerShell" build step where Script arguments section looks like this:

**Script arguments:** `%powershell.args01%`

**Problem**

I have 3 Build Configurations that inherit from the above template.  This setup works perfectly in all 3 configurations.  Today, I'm copying one of the configurations to create yet a forth configuration that would inherit from the above template.  All of a sudden, in this line

```
-username %deployment.username% -password %deployment.password% -computer %deployment.destinationServer01%
```

`%deployment.destinationServer01%` does not get evaluated anymore and just gets passed to my script as *%deployment.destinationServer01%* as oppose to its actual value.  Both `%deployment.username%` and `%deployment.password%` are still evaluated fine.

I don't know what differences to look for, because there aren't any.  This is defined in a template and all three configurations that inherit from it work just fine.  The only difference is that this 4th config has a dependency on one of the other 3 configs.  But this involves playing with Artifacts.  I don't change the script or the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to check:

- Is the fourth (new) build config also associated with the same template?
- Are the 4 parameters defined at the template, or on the build configs (or on a project containing these build configs)?
- Does the fourth build config belong to the same project as the three?
- Is the `%deployment.destinationServer01%` parameter visible to the fourth build config? (Add a build step and start typing `%deplo...` - does TC auto-complete it?)

If all else fails, open the TC data directory (either by logging on to the server or by browsing it in the TC Admin GUI - read [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Data+Directory#TeamCityDataDirectory-LocationoftheTeamCityDataDirectory)) and diff the XML files of the working configs with the XML file of the non-working fourth config. There's got to be a difference :-)

Comment: Hi. The template is on Root Project level.  %powershell.args01% is defined in the template and locked.  deployment.username & deployment.password are also locked. The only param I can change is %deployment.destinationServer01%, which no matter what I type for the value does not get evaluated.  That's it.  There is nothing to "play with". I can't start typing %... to see if param comes up because it's locked in the template.  I'll most likely will have to dig into XML on the server side when I'll have time.  For now, I'm going around the template - deadlines are tight.  Thank you for the reply!

Comment: In the fourth build config, you can add a step (in addition to those derived from the template). You can start typing `%...` in this new step. Also, have you tried unlocking all the params, since that's obviously a difference that could be causing the behaviour?